# Android start activity with button?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

i keep getting a null pointer exception

I have a problem about starting a new activity via using button.

I already checked the previous questions related to mine problem, one of them is almost same but solutions didn't work out for me. So here is my problem.

whenever i start the app it crashes.
i have a main class called MainActivity and new Activity called login

Main class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, login.class);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button loginButton  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_login);


        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

logcat

```
02-18 10:27:42.520    1098-1098/com.example.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.app, PID: 1098
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

thanks in advance!!!

EDIT---> MANIFEST

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.login"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOGIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.app.MainActivity">

    //login Button
    <Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        android:id="@+id/button_login"
        android:layout_marginBottom="160dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp" />

    //high score button
    <Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="high score"
        android:id="@+id/highScore"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_login"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_login"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp" />

    //play Button
    <Button
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Play"
        android:id="@+id/Play"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_login"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="55dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Edited corrections with imports

```
package com.example.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button loginButton  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_login);

//        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
//            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
//                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
//                    .commit();
//        }

        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, login.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Share your manifest.xml. I think the problem is with your package definition in the manifest

Comment: Button loginButton  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_login); can you check the value of login button ? or else post your main_activity layout xml

Comment: Try below code and let me know whether it is working or not.

Comment: if it helps, you can accept an answer as correct :)

Comment: @RajeshCP i added the layout

Answer (score 3):

Move this inside the onCreate method :

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, login.class);
```

By using that line outside the method, you are referring to the instance of MainActivity before it is fully created.

Since it looks like you are only using that intent once, you could even move that line inside the onClick method of the loginButton's OnClickListener, as suggested by InnocentKiller.

Comment: Define "didn't work" ... You still got an error/crash (and if so, which one) ? It's not doing what you want ?

Comment: Which line is line 30 in MainActivity ?

Comment: loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

Comment: You didn't include your imports, maybe you are not importing the correct R.java class ? Please check you are importing com.example.app.R and not android.R. Your NPE on that line most likely means that your button is null... Could you show your edited code to check everything looks right (and remove the code for login.java as it is not relevant to your issue) ? Thanks !

Comment: done! i added the edited text and also showed imports.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you further, everything looks right to me ... You could probably remove the Fragment related code and imports since you are not using those but it can't be what is causing the problem, just for code clarity's sake. You seem to also be missing the R import in the edited code you added.

Comment: i figured it out my setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) was wrong i was doing it in faragment_main

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line from top of your screen

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, login.class);
```

and put under the button click event. So basically your code will something like this for MainActivity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button loginButton  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_login);


    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, login.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
............
...........

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an Intent!

try:

```
loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
```

Your login class should also be named "Login" to serve the name convention

And you need to add the new Login.class to your Manifest like

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.yourapp.Login"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Login activity declared on your manifest as an activity

```
  <activity
        android:name="com.examlpe.app.loginActivity"/>
```

Comment: A missing Activity in the manifest will produce ActivityNotFoundException, not NullPointerException as shown in the provided stack trace.